# MVC Index page and filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This seems like a very simple question, but I'm getting lost, and need a few pointers.

I am using ASP.NET MVC C#, and have an Index page which displays a list of items, which is working fine.

Now I'm trying to add a DropDownList that depending on what the user selects will filter the list of items.  But I keep thinking how you would do this in ASP.NET Web with RunAt Server, which I know is wrong.

Any pointers would be welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the select box in a form and make the form post back to a filter method in your controller. 
Or
If you want to use ajax, use an Ajax.ActionLink to update the table with the filtered results

```
<% Ajax.ActionLink("Filter", "FilterMethod", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tableId" }, new { Title = "Filter results" }) %>
<table id="tableId"> .... </table>
```

Where "FilterMethod" is in yo0ur controller

Comment: You can also have two different actions with the same name that respond to different REST verbs.  For instance, you can have a "GET" index, and a "POST" index, where the POST index will do filtering based on the value submitted by the view that the GET index rendered.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth looking at:

http://jerrytech.blogspot.com/2009/06/implement-ajax-form-in-mvc-framework.html